AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' data = self._translate
from googletrans import Translator, LANGCODES
Translator = Translator()
with open("bad_blood.txt",mode="r", encoding='utf-8') as textFile:
    text = textFile.read()
translation = Translator.translate(text, src="en", dest="fa")    
print(translation)

These are the errors of my code and it does not run, I don't know why?
 File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 182, in translate
    data = self._translate(text, dest, src, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\googletrans\client.py", line 78, in _translate
    token = self.token_acquirer.do(text)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 194, in do
    self._update()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\googletrans\gtoken.py", line 62, in _update
    code = self.RE_TKK.search(r.text).group(1).replace('var ', '')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

